# tensorflow&iOS not file "xxx.pb.h"

Tags: tensorflow

iOS Build TensorFlow with code.

I found that `.pb.h` file is not find. However, there were same name `".proto"` file, why is happened?

Answer (score 0):

.ph.h is a generated file when you build with bazel build.  The .ph.h files should appear under bazel-genfiles folder thereafter.

Check out the instructions on bazel build for tensorflow here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources